# Insert image object into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm just curious to know if there's a better solution for doing this:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('foo');

img.onload = function() {
  div.innerHTML += '<img src="'+img.src+'" />'; 
};

img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
```

Desired method:

```
console.log(img); // <img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
div.innerHTML += img;
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('foo');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
```

You already have a loaded image object.  You should just append it directly into the DOM rather than create a whole new image object with `innerHTML`.

In addition using `+=` with `innerHTML` is very wasteful as it takes all the objects you already have in there, converts them to HTML text, adds onto that text and then makes all new DOM objects - losing all event handlers when it makes new objects too.  It's way, way more efficient to just add a new DOM object onto the set of existing DOM object.

In addition, `document.getElementById()` takes the id without a `#` in front of it.

Comment: when `onload` is fired? after setting `.src`?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - Based on the OP's original code, the OP probably doesn't want the image object inserted until it's loaded so there are no display artifacts during loading.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake on the `#`, I rushed the question.

Comment: Amazing answer!!  I was having a problem with <img/> firing multiple onload events each and this solved it!  In my case I used a single `.innerHTML =` to solve it, but I just didn't realize all the old HTML got re-evaluated every time I append.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('theDiv');

img.onload = function() {
  div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
```

Comment: This will not work in IE when the image is in the browser cache.  Setting the `onload` hander AFTER setting `.src` is a problem in IE.  If the image is in the browser cache, the `load` event will fire BEFORE you have the `onload` handler in place and you will miss the event and the code will not work.

Comment: Oh thanks. Will update it. :) So, I will bring the `img.src` after the `.onload()` function. Actually this becomes identical to your answer!

Comment: Which now makes it an exact copy of my answer except you haven't removed the `#` from `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I said! :(