# How to add an image in a function on javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a function in java script which has some text but now i want to add  an image too.

How to insert an image inside the function ?

Here is the JAVASCRIPT code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CONshowElements(){
        var Construction = "The construction company with several years of experience in projects valued over millions of USD having Service and Quality with satisfaction and appreciation of the clients";

       document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Construction;
       var image = new Image;
      image.src = "images/SCALE Construction.png";
          }
      </script>
```

Body code

```
  <a href="construction.php"><div class="firstbox" id="Construction" onmouseover="CONshowElements(); return false; " >Construction</div></a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert image object into HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287856/insert-image-object-into-html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want just move image to `var Construction` so it will be

```
var Construction = 'The construction company with several years of experience in projects valued over millions of USD having Service and Quality with satisfaction and appreciation of the clients <img src="images/SCALE Construction.png">';
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this answer:

```
function CONshowElements(){
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.setAttribute("src","images/SCALE Construction.png");
   document.body.appendChild(img);
   return false;
}
document.getElementById("Construction").onclick = CONshowElements;
```

See it:http://jsfiddle.net/yuanzm/x0zs7gb1/